# if conditions are not working after where clause in Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I am creating a Mysql stored procedure. What I want to do here is to add multiple and conditions if parameters values are not empty. I have written a query inside the stored procedure but it is not working.

Here is the query

```
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        c.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, u.email, 
        c.name, c.raised_amount, c.goal_amount, c.created_at 
    FROM
        users u
    INNER JOIN 
        city c ON u.id = c.user_id 
    WHERE 
        c.user_id = user_id 

    IF( city_name !='', and c.name LIKE CONCAT('%',city_name, '%') , 1)

    IF( city_raised_max != '' AND city_raised_min != '', and c.raised_amount BETWEEN city_raised_min AND city_raised_max , '%'), 1);   

END
```

These three are the parameters

1. user_id
2. city_raised_min
3. city_raised_max

What I want to here is that i want to add multiple and conditions if parameters are not empty.

but the query is giving me syntax error on this line you have an error in your sql syntax error check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax near.

```
IF( city_name !='', and c.name LIKE CONCAT('%',city_name, '%') , 1)
```

Kindly help me on this issue i have trying to resolve this for 1 day but still no success.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: That syntax i awful, I don't even know where to start telling the wrong parts...

Comment: you didn't understand if syntax if(condition,then,else)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html There is no IF at all, you didn't understand the mysql syntax as well I guess. Also if(condition,then,else) is not valid mysql syntax. mysql uses `case when a then b else c end`

Comment: @Psi can you please correct me where i am wrong in the syantax..

Comment: Everywhere (at least starting from the first `IF`)! Have a look at Forward's answer. And read the documentation about select statements in my last comment. There are non-matching brackets, commas where there shouldn't be any, a `1` in the end which makes no sense at all... shall I go on?

Comment: @Psi the forward solution is not working...

Comment: Because he forgot some brackets. I will show answer with brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `or` to do the trick:

```
BEGIN

    Select c.user_id,u.fname,u.lname,u.email,c.name,c.raised_amount,c.goal_amount,c.created_at from users u
    INNER JOIN city c on u.id = c.user_id 

    WHERE c.user_id=user_id 

    AND (city_name = '' OR city_name IS NULL OR c.name LIKE CONCAT('%',city_name, '%'))

    AND (city_raised_max  = '' OR city_raised_max IS NULL OR city_raised_max >= c.raised_amount)

    AND (city_raised_min = '' OR city_raised_min IS NULL OR city_raised_min <= c.raised_amount)
END
```

***Edit***:

How does this query work?
Take `(city_name = '' OR city_name IS NULL OR c.name LIKE CONCAT('%',city_name, '%'))` as an example:

if `city_name = ''` is true, then expressions after first `or` will not be calculated;
if `city_name = ''` is false, then if `city_name IS NULL` is true, then expressions after second `or` will not be calculated;
if `city_name = ''` and `city_name IS NULL` are false, the last expression will be calculated.

besides, here you have three criterias, of cause we should use `and`.

Comment: How did you know what he meant with ,1 in the end of the statements? You just ignored them in your answer (which I would have done, too)

Comment: @Psi in the end i am using 1 because if the condition city_name !=''" is not true then in the query string the AND should become like this AND = 1 so that this condition does not become false...

Comment: That's not the way it works. This answer shows you the correct way to do it

Comment: @Forward you should place brackets around the `... OR ...` statements to match the operator priority, otherwise your code does strange things (`and` stronger than `or`)

Comment: @Forward it is not working it is always returning true and giving me all the records even if i provide a non existing city name...

Comment: About your input variables, they are not empty string, they're null, right? @usama

Comment: @usama I've updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: @Forward your answer is working correctly can you please explain what i as doing wrong and why we are using And outside and OR inside the brackets and why not if else..

Comment: or either the case when instead if and or

Comment: Beyond all, I believe you should know how `or` works, see my ***Edit*** part.

Comment: Thanks @Forward i know how or work just wanted to know the reason why we did not use the Case when and the if else condition...
If you can explain reasons of this then it will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Forward's Answer with correct brackets and corrected comparison to maintain the logic:

BEGIN

```
Select c.user_id,u.fname,u.lname,u.email,c.name,c.raised_amount,c.goal_amount,c.created_at from users u
INNER JOIN city c on u.id = c.user_id 

WHERE c.user_id=user_id 

AND (city_name = '' OR c.name LIKE CONCAT('%',city_name, '%'))

AND (city_raised_max = '' OR city_raised_min = '' OR c.raised_amount BETWEEN city_raised_min AND city_raised_max);
```

END

Comment: Thanks it is working can you please explain it a little bit what i was doing wrong...?

Comment: and why we are using And outside and OR inside the brackets and why not if else

Comment: or either the case when instead if and or

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your query. Try to replace it with :

```
IF( city_name != '' and c.name LIKE CONCAT('%',city_name, '%'))
```

Comment: My bad, you right. Like you I don't know where to start telling the mistakes